# insert SD card before using the camera Alert . android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, android-activity

what i'm trying to do is: to open the camera and save the taken picture in the SD card, but when the camera activity start, i receive an automatic generated warning displayed in a "toast" and says:
"insert SD card before using the camera "

note: I'm using the emulator.

any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create an AVD it's possible to say whether to emulate SDCard or not (and of what size). Looks like you simply did not specify the SDCard presence. Edit your AVD settings and make sure you have explicitly requested for SDCard support.

Comment: @psychicLit: in the bottom there is a list of hardware, make sure to select (using "New.." button) SDCard property and set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same toast error message.  Seems it a problem that can also occure with a real device. In my case, I was able solve the problem just by using the virtual device interface. I clicked on the SD card icon from the home screen (on top left corner in my case), I accepted to use the SD card only in this android device, I accept the move of files to the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by increasing the size of the SD card in the AVD Manager, I had 100 MB then I uploaded it to 512 MB and the message disappeared

Answer (score -1):

Okay. After spending more than enough time changing AVD manager settings it seems Adan's answer pointed me in the right direction. However, I had to increase my SD card: studio-managed setting to 1024(GB) for the message to disappear and the camera button to take the picture.

Answer (score -2):

Most of the time we ignore the options when creating AVD, and later realize that we didnt select these options. Also make sure that you select the appropriate front and back camera.